# Edit existing row in mysql with Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, connection

I have an existing row in my database that i want to add to it is structured like this

`id , firstname, lastname, username, email , password , about , freinds , profilePicDir , ip`

i want the user to be able to add a freind and i am storeing there values in the db so i used this

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO users (freinds) VALUES  (' + freind + ') WHERE username = ? ', [username], function(err) {});
```

but its not spitting out any errors or anything there is just nothing happening i know that the function is being called but that just wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the job for `insert` command.

You have to use `update` **mysql** command. The result will be handled in the `callback` method of the **query**.

```
let query='update users set freinds="' + freind + '" where username = "'+ username+'"';
connection.query(query, function(err) {

});
```

Comment: oh i thought update would clear all the existing data and just add the new thank you very much i will try that

Comment: @NicholasHendricks, tell me when you finished in order to help you in case you failed.

Comment: I am getting this error `Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'username = Nik' at line 1`

Comment: is there any way i can add to the existing data in the database